# Open/Close Operation Equivalence VB6 / VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am working on converting parts of a VB6 Project to VB.Net and there are some code segments I am having issues with because I can't seem to find alternatives for the VB6 code in VB.Net.  Here is the code block in question right now:

```
Public Sub ProcessError(ByVal strModule As String, ByVal strProcedure As String, _
                        ByVal strDescription As String, ByVal bLogError As Boolean, _
                        ByVal bShowError As Boolean, Optional ByVal strMsg As String)
    On Error GoTo 100
    Dim intFile As Integer: Dim strPathName As String
    strPathName = AddBackSlash(gsLogPath) & gsErrLogName
    If bLogError = True Then
        If GetFileSize(strPathName) > gcuMaxLogFileSize Then
            Call CopyFile(strPathName, strPathName & ".bak")
            Call DeleteFile(strPathName)
        End If
        intFile = FreeFile
        Open strPathName For Append As #intFile
        Write #intFile, Format(Now, "MMM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS AMPM"), strModule, strProcedure, strDescription)
        Close #intFile
    End If
    If bShowError Then
        Call Prompt("Error occurred in " & strModule & vbCrLf & "Error Description :" & strDescription, 1, vbRed)
    End If
    Exit Sub
100:
    Close #intFile
End Sub
```

So the lines I am having issue with are:

```
Open strPathName For Append As #intFile
Write #intFile
Close #intFile
```

I understand I should probably be using the `StreamWriter` object in place of these, but what throws me off is the Error section.  If an error is thrown and it goes to the `100` mark, how would `Close #intFile` work if it hasn't been opened or created yet?

For most of the other conversion annoyances I've had with porting this over this one has been confusing me the most, so any help is appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Disposable classes can use a Using-End Using block, which will automatically dispose the object, even in the event of an exception.  Don't use GoTo.  Use a proper Try-Catch instead.

Comment: With respect to your question about the `Close`, your legacy code works because the `Close #filenumber` statement does not throw an error if the referenced file number is not open. If the file number is open, it's closed, otherwise it's just going to remain closed and no error.

Comment: @LarsTech Yeah I have been converting the `GoTo` blocks to proper `Try/Catch` blocks for error handling.  With concerns to the first part of your comment, are you saying I could set up a `Using` block for `StreamWriter` and if there is an error it automatically disposes the object?

Comment: @Skitzafreak Yes.  Behind the scenes, a Using-End Using block sets up a Try-Catch-Finally that does dispose the object in the Finally branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixes the errors, and also updates a lot of the code to use styles and APIs more typical for modern VB.Net. For this to work as-is, make sure there is an `Imports System.IO` directive at the top of the file.

```
Public Sub ProcessError(ByVal ModuleName As String, ByVal ProcedureName As String, _
                        ByVal Description As String, ByVal LogError As Boolean, _
                        ByVal ShowError As Boolean, Optional ByVal Message As String)

    If LogError Then
        Dim logFile As New FileInfo(Path.Combine(gsLogPath, gsErrLogName))
        If logFile.Length > gcuMaxLogFileSize Then
            logFile.MoveTo(logFile.FullName & ".bak")
        End If

        Try
            File.AppendAllText(PathName, String.Format("{0:d},""{1}"",""{2}"",""{3}""", DateTime.Now, ModuleName, ProcedureName, Description))
        Catch
        End Try
    End If

    If ShowError Then
        MsgBox(String.Format("Error occurred in {0}{1}Error Description:{2}", ModuleName, vbCrLf, Description))
    End If

End Sub
```

One thing worth pointing out here is the [style guidelines published by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) for VB.Net now *explicitly recommend against hungarian type-prefixes.*

Comment: I'd love to not use Hungarian Notation, but my boss yells at me when I don't :P

Comment: If it helps... it's not me, it's Microsoft. They published guidelines for VB6, too, and those guidelines **did** suggest hungarian. This is an explicit reversal by the creator of the language, based on updated support in the tooling to make this information available to developers in other ways.

Comment: I am aware lol.  Honestly I hate that my boss has me using Hungarian Notation because for me it's just bad variable notation.  You shouldn't need to preface a variable name with it's datatype.  The datatype should be obvious based off of the variable name.  For example instead of `nPlayers` I would use `NumOfPlayers` or `NumberOfPlayers` if I felt like typing out a few extra characters.  It also helps to make code logic more readable.  But I can't explain that to the big guy and have him accept it T__T

Comment: Not sure this is exactly equivalent to the VB? The VB6 version will write the file in "ANSI" encoding whereas AFAICR the VB.Net will use UTF-8. This may not matter for the OP, depending on what characters are likely to appear in the strings. If outputting text that uses characters outside the ASCII 0-127 range (e.g. Chinese, Japanese, etc etc) it matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have one line to write to, you can use the build-in method that does all the work for you.

```
Dim inputString As String = "This is a test string."
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(
  "C://testfile.txt", inputString, True)
```

More help here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-append-to-text-files?view=netframework-4.7.2